# how do one do this question: Let f : B → R be continuous, where B is the closed unit disk in R2. Show that f can not be one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

I came across this question in Martin Moskowitz Functions of several real variables. Please someone help me with this.
Let f : B → R be continuous, where B is the closed unit disk in R2. Show that f can not be one-to-one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Consider continuous one to one restriction map $f: S^1 \to R$. Use connectedness argument.